# Javascript automatically increment year in Date class

Tags: javascript

So I am working on a Javascript calendar to reflect the current month along with the last few days of last month, and the first few days of the next month. I've ran into an issue I can't figure out for the life of me.

I have the following

```
var today = new Date();
var lastMonthDays =  new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() - 1, 0).getDate();
```

This should return the last day of the last month respectively, but it's giving me the value 31 which represents 31 days, however, in April there is only 30 days. So my best guess is that it's giving me the current months number of days. Shouldn't this be giving me 30? I've looked at other examples online and from what it looks like, what I have right now should work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's giving you 31 because **March** has 31 days.  Try this:

```
var lastMonthDays =  new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 0).getDate();
```

The 0 in the day-of-month field effectively means "the day before the 1st of this month".

Comment: Okay. That makes sense. So my next question is going to be, how would I get THIS months last day? Right now, I am using that same exact code to get this months last and now I am seeing that it's not right. Whould I do `new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth()+, 0).getDate();`

Comment: Yes, just get day zero of the next month (`today.getMonth()+1`).

Answer (score 2):

today.getMonth() gives a zero-indexed month. i.e.

Jan: 0,
Feb: 1,
Mar: 2,
...

Therefore you don't need the -1 to get the previous month

```
var today = new Date();
var lastMonthDays =  new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 0).getDate();
```

Comment: You're right about not needing to subtract one, but it's because of the 1-based day-of-month, not the 0-based month-of-year.

Comment: You're right - I forget you also feed the month in as a zero-indexed month (obviously!) so the the indexing is of no relevance. Your answer is correct.